# Why does not DataGrid show values if there are a point "." or "/" in header of column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I've found really strange behavior in `DataGrid`. I cannot figured out why it happens, but `DataGrid` does not show values if  there are a point `"."` or `"/"` in header of column.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridWpfApplication.MainWindow"
  <!--the code omitted for the brevity-->
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
         <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   PopulateDataGrid();
}

private void PopulateDataGrid()
{
   var _ds = new DataSet("Test");
   var employeeDataTable = new DataTable();
   employeeDataTable = _ds.Tables.Add("DT");
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
   {
       employeeDataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString() + ".");//No Data in values
       //employeeDataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString());//Data in values
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
       var theRow = employeeDataTable.NewRow();
       for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
       {
          if (j % 2 == 0)
          {
             theRow[j] = "a";
          }
          else
            theRow[j] = "b";
       }
       employeeDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow);
    }
   dataGrid.ItemsSource = employeeDataTable.AsDataView();
}
```

**My question is how can I put "." and "/" in header of column and show data?**

**Update:**

[I wrote an answer in the previous question. Please, go here!:)](http://WPF%20Datagrid%20binding%20errors%20with%20dots%20in%20column%20headers)

Comment: You might be able to do this with a converter.  Change a _ to .  And something else to /.  On / I think you just need to escape it.

Comment: @Frisbee Magnus Montin helped me to solve this question in elegant way.  It is possible to see in link provided at the bottom of my question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765308/wpf-datagrid-binding-errors-with-dots-in-column-headers/34102127#34102127